# Apply a Sub Procedure to Two Column in a Table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of data where one column is Units, one column is UnitCost, and a column that doesn't exist that I would like to populate is Total.

I would like to multiply Units by UnitCost to populate each row in Total.

I get the Error Message:

> "Object variable or With Block variable not set"

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()
Dim Units As Range, UnitCost As Range, Total As Range
Units = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E44").Value
UnitCost = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:F44").Value
Total = Units * UnitCost
Range("H2:H44").Value = Total
End Sub
```

Do I need to change my datatypes from range to double?

Comment: Yes, you need to change your datatypes, `Range` variables are meant  to hold ranges or cells, you are giving it a number. Plus, a range object, any object for that matter, needs to be set with `Set Units = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E44")` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few things to straighten out. In addition to @Damian's comment above, it seems that you're trying to use memory-based arrays along with ranges. This is perfectly fine, but you've made no distinction between which is a `Range` and which is an array. Then you're trying to multiply two entire ranges (or arrays) using `Total = Units * UnitCost`. This won't work either.

This example code shows you how to clearly define the variables you're using and ***how*** you're using them. Remember to [always use `Option Explicit`](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()
    Dim unitsArea As Range
    Dim unitsData As Variant
    Set unitsArea = Sheet1.Range("E2:E44")
    unitsData = unitsArea

    Dim unitCostArea As Range
    Dim unitCostData As Variant
    Set unitCostArea = Sheet1.Range("F2:F44")
    unitCostData = unitCostArea

    '--- create an array for results the same size as the inputs
    Dim totals As Variant
    ReDim totals(LBound(unitsData) To UBound(unitsData), 1 To 1)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(totals) To UBound(totals)
        totals(i, 1) = unitsData(i, 1) * unitCostData(i, 1)
    Next i

    '--- finally copy the results back to the worksheet
    Dim totalsArea As Range
    Set totalsArea = Sheet1.Range("H2:H44")
    totalsArea = totals
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to explain this to me. Unfortunately after running the block of code above I am getting a 'Subscript out of range' Error Message on the following line: totals(i) = unitsData(i) * unitCostData(i)

Comment: also should this line ReDim totals(LBound(unitsData) To UBound(unitsData)) be converted to ReDim totals(LBound(unitsData) To UBound(unitCostData))?

Comment: I forgot to add an extra dimension to the arrays for transferring back and forth between a `Range` and a `Variant` array. The code above has been fixed and updated.

Comment: Thank you so much!